# "Duplicate Symbols" linker error

Tags: ios, xcode

What is this error in IOS 7:

```
d: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What's the products folder for with MyApp.app and .xctest

Comment: i think a little more of the error message would help. like @Neva says, and your error message says, there are duplicate symbols "2 duplicate symbols". it could be because of many reasons..

Comment: Will you write the whole error i think this is the framework error.

Comment: Check your include statements.This occoured when the .m file is imported

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that you have a file that is linked twice, such as twice the same framework for instance. Check on libs and files you included recently.